# Android emulator Error:- executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to run my first Android App on `Android Emulator` on `API 19`. The `Emulator` get started but nothing comes up, means Home screen is not appearing. Its my second week on `Android`

These are the first two lines of log cat.

```
   02-21 05:45:32.410: E/logwrapper(41): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
    02-21 05:45:32.560: E/logwrapper(44): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
```

Some more errors are.

```
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:90)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.writeUserList(UserManager.java:202)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.fallbackToSingleUser(UserManager.java:153)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.readUserList(UserManager.java:109)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:81)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:85)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:923)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
02-21 06:11:18.318: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:90)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.writeUser(UserManager.java:167)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.fallbackToSingleUser(UserManager.java:154)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.readUserList(UserManager.java:109)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:81)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:85)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:923)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
02-21 06:11:18.570: E/StrictMode(94):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
```

Comment: Post the Whole Log for Reference :)

Comment: @nitesh `logcat` never ends. I waited for 40 minutes and nothing happens. I can't paste the full `logcat` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the emulator was unable to mount the file system because of errors. The underlying file system for the emulator was changed to ext4 and e2fsprogs utilities were not included. These utilities are required by the kernel for proper operation. On OSX and Linux you can use the standard e2fsprogs utilities to repair the file system.

```
# Navigate to AVD
cd ~/.android/avd/Nexus5
e2fsck -f userdata-qemu.img
```

There is a e2fsprogs package available for Cygwin but I haven't tested it. This issue has been corrected for future distributions. See: [e2fsck missing from emulator](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/73226/).

If you still cannot boot the emulator after running e2fsck post the kernel log by adding `-show-kernel` to the emulator command line.

Comment: Its working fine in `MAC` Os. Only problem is with windows. Switching to `API 17`, simulator is still taking time about 30 min to start.

Comment: ▲ for pointing out regarding OSX and Linux. I tried to searched but could not found this article.

Comment: You should post the kernel log if you still cannot get it to boot.

Answer (score 3):

After checking your issue, I tried it too , to check whether emulator is opening the home page or not. I am sharing what I tried, it might work for you too.

**1. First install all android SDK Build Tools for 19 API**

See the below Image for reference :

[image]

**2. Go To AVD Manager and click New , and select API level 19 and screen size  as per your need. See below image for reference what I took in my case.**

[image]

**3.And then start your emulator created, It worked in my case.**

Comment: I already had tried this two times and wasted two days. Now I have changed my system which is having higher RAM and every thing is fine on this system.

Comment: Down Voters!! Please comment here. I just shared what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my `SDK` but still same problem.

Only solution I found is :- I updated my `SDK` for lower `API`'s and switched over to lover `API` like `17` and my `emulator` get started. But still can not get the features of `API 19`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer AJ,

a change in the file format was applied to android OS images in Dec, but e2fsck was not included in build..

update your sdk ie the android OS emulator images and re create your AVDs and that should resolve the problem.

Comment: I created a new AVD and when I ran `adb shell ls /system/bin/ | grep e2fsck` nothing showed. Re-creating the AVD will definitely fix any corrupted file system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self that I had to edit the AVD skin to use “skin with dynamic hardware controls”