# executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory

Tags: android

I tried to develop my first application on android. My DDMS has following error.

"executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory"

what can be cause?

Comment: Check this link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926448/android-emulator-error-executing-system-bin-e2fsck-failed-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: i am on API 19 and installed all build tools. Still same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the emulator was unable to mount the file system because of errors. The underlying file system for the emulator was changed to ext4 and e2fsprogs utilities were not included. These utilities are required by the kernel for proper operation. On OSX and Linux you can use the standard e2fsprogs utilities to repair the file system.

```
# Navigate to AVD
cd ~/.android/avd/Nexus5
e2fsck -f userdata-qemu.img
```

There is a e2fsprogs package available for Cygwin but I haven't tested it. This issue has been corrected for future distributions. See: e2fsck missing from emulator.

If you still cannot boot the emulator after running e2fsck post the kernel log by adding -show-kernel to the emulator command line.