# Error with Android Studio: Cannot launch AVD in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

The ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1.

I have made sure that I follow this video exactly when setting up my AVD. Whenever I run the AVD with the x86_64 System Image, I get the following message:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: Creating filesystem with
>   parameters: Size: 69206016 Block size: 4096 Blocks per group: 32768
>   ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1 Inodes per
>   group: 4224 Inode size: 256 Journal blocks: 1024 Label: Blocks: 16896
>   Block groups: 1 Reserved block group size: 7 Created filesystem with
>   11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks Hax is enabled Hax ram_size
>   0x60000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>   emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554 emulator:
>   Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554 emulator:
>   WARNING: The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored.

Whenever I run it with the regular x86 System Image, I get this message:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: WARNING: userdata
>   partition is resized from 550 M to 800 M ERROR: resizing partition
>   e2fsck failed with exit code 1 Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x60000000
>   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. emulator:
>   Listening for console connections on port: 5554 emulator: Serial
>   number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554 emulator: WARNING:
>   The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored.

I have a computer that is a 64-bit system that runs Windows 10. I have tried both the Lollipop 22 x86_64 and Lollipop 22 x86 System Images and they both fail.

I cannot figure out what the issue is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Any chance you have Docker installed on your system ?? (there is a conflict between the two..)

Comment: I am not sure to be honest.  Would that be something that comes preinstalled on an MSI gaming laptop?  I just got this laptop a few weeks ago.

Comment: No, don't think so...

Answer (score 4):

set Memory=1024 MB
and Internal storage =550 MB
I have solved this error for my emulator

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> resizing partition e2fsck failed

This can happen if the underlying file system for that AVD has errors, and the emulator is unable to mount it. It isn't exactly straight forward to fix e2fsck for that file system in Windows, but its possible.

At this point, it'll be important to add that using [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com) could be easier and perfectly normal in your case.

To solve the partition issue on Windows:

Install Cygwin and run the e2fsck cmd

```
# Navigate to AVD
cd ~/.android/avd/Nexus5
e2fsck -f userdata-qemu.img
```

For more information, refer to the following links:

https://superuser.com/questions/739710/running-fsck-from-cygwin-shell

[Android emulator Error:- executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926448/android-emulator-error-executing-system-bin-e2fsck-failed-no-such-file-or-di)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error and all i had to do to fix this is change my android sdk location. Android studio warned me not to use spaces in folder names, but I still did and that caused this error.

Comment: Boom! This fixed it!  Thank you so much Synth.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the VM Heap size to 512 MB which is the minimum required size.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who already done theses answers and do not had success i will recommend to re-install your emulator, this worked here.