# Emulator: ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter

Hallo I am trying t run my flutter application with Android Studio but i get every time this error:

```
Emulator: ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1
```

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: What Flutter version? What OS? How did you run the app.

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621715/error-with-android-studio-cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator to me

Comment: The Flutter Version is flutter_windows_v0.2.8-beta.zip
And my Operating system is Windows 10
I had problems by adding a virtual device because of my AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core 3.50 CPU before maybe that is the problem :/
The selected device uses arm.

Answer (score 1):

Other people answer to that question on SOF because many users had that problem.
If you search for "**e2fsck failed with exit code 8**" on Google you will find them.
Unfortunately, no one of them was able to help to overcome the problem for me.

### **My Solution**

I solved this way (I hope it can help for someone): I download and installed the Android Emulator stable version from Android Official Site https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/08/emulator-27310-stable.html.
I extracted all the files contained in the .zip and I dragged and dropped to the path %ANDROID_HOME%/tools where the emulator is located and it works.

Reguards.